# Add "Copy Filename" to tab context menu in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, tabs, contextmenu

Currently there is "Copy Full Path" in the tab context menu. 
I would like to have a "Copy Filename" item in it. I looked at Tools -> Customize -> Commands -> Context menu -> Other Context Menus | Easy MDI Document Window -> Add Command -> Categories -> File, but couldn't find any such command. Is it not possible to add such an item in any way?

Answer (score 1):

As of Visual Studio 2013, there is still no builtin command to do what you want.

But it is no reason to think “it is not possible to add such an item in any way". If you notice, Visual Studio extensions add their own commands to the list, so you can either develop your own extension or find one that provides the command you've mentioned.

**Edit**: Visual Studio 2017 still doesn't have that builtin command.

**Edit**: Visual Studio 2019 still doesn't have that builtin command.

Comment: If anyone has developed this extension, please add it to the marketplace. Thanks.